# Chrome Developer Tool does not show localStorage data although type in console command "localStorage" show data is not empty

Tags: google-chrome, local-storage, developer-tools

[localStorage in Application show blank](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D1wnQ.png)
[but when check in console, there is data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XKyWR.png)

Clicking the refresh icon/button to the left of the filter input doesn't change anything.

I have searched all around the internet but doesn't seem to get any work around or solution to fix this.

Comment: Show the application's localStorage is blank.

Comment: There are at least 4 issues regarding this on google's issue tracker first one from 2nd jan [1404388](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=1404388&q=localstorage&can=2), [1408031](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=1408031&q=localstorage&can=2), [1409357](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=1409357&q=localstorage&can=2), [1411181](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=1411181&q=localstorage&can=2)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just completing what @Greg have said.

#### Solution

If you happen to have this problem **simply open new page**, you don't have to open a new browser. I happen to face this when I was creating my Vue app and integrating it with Amazon Cognito.

I have no proof over what happens. But it could be because I rarely shutdown my laptop so when I opened up my laptop my dev environment still there. And maybe something happens there? Just a theory tho'.

Answer (score 0):

We had this issue just today with a number of the browsers in the office. Nothing showed in the developer console under local or session storage, even though the web application would not work without data stored there. We also had cases where parts of the web application were using code which was not deployed on the web server either.

After we restarted the browser the local/session storage reappeared and we were able to use the web application without issue. It would appear that there was some disconnect between the browser and the working parts of the browser and may have been caused by an upgrade which happened while the browser was in-use but did not take full effect until it was restarted.